# Line shown behind filled rectangle made with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to create a TikZ style that is a filled rectangle with a line crossing it.

The problem I'm facing now is that when the rectangle is filled with a color, then the line is drawn behind the rectangle, and I need it above.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.geometric}

\tikzstyle{mainfig} = [
    minimum width=16mm,
    minimum height=5mm,
    text centered,
    draw=black,
    fill=orange!80,
    line width=1pt,
    rectangle,
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{
        \draw [line width=2pt]
            ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(3mm,5mm)$)--
            ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(3mm,-5mm)$);
      } 
    }   
] 

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
    \node (test) [mainfig] {\ldots};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

How can I force the line drawn after `append after command` to be drawn above the filled figure?

---

**Update:**

I've confirmed that this code doesn't work with pgf 2.10, nor with 3.0.0.

Also, I've seen that this problem is perfectly solvable using pgf 3.0.0, thanks to the answers of @PaulGessler and @PaulGaborit, but for now I should like a solution working for both versions of pgf. I hope that is not too much to ask for.

In particular, I need a working solution with pgf 2.10 support, because I will use this code in a project to be worked collaboratively, and as of now, both ShareLaTeX and writeLaTeX use that version of pgf.

If nothing new appears, I will gladly accept the most voted of those answers.

Comment: Did you update to v3.00 ?

Comment: No, I have pgf version 2.10 (TexLive 2012).

Answer (score 8):

One method is to use layers. Declare the foreground (`fg`) layer with `\pgfdeclarelayer{fg}` and set the order of layers (bottom to top) with `\pgfsetlayers{main,fg}`.

Then, anywhere in a `pgf`-based environment, you can use

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{fg}
  <drawing commands>
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

to draw in the foreground.

A note: the `shapes.geometric` library is not required; `rectangle` is included in the base package.

**The Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfdeclarelayer{fg} % declare foreground layer
\pgfsetlayers{main,fg} % set layer order

\tikzstyle{mainfig} = [
    minimum width=16mm,
    minimum height=5mm,
    text centered,
    draw=black,
    fill=orange!80,
    line width=1pt,
    rectangle,
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{fg}
          \draw [line width=2pt]
            ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(3mm,5mm)$)--
            ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(3mm,-5mm)$);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
      } 
    }   
] 

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
    \node (test) [mainfig] {\ldots};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]

Comment: This example doesn't work for me.
BTW, I'm using TexLive 2012. I think I should not need a so up-to-date version to get working something as simple as this, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Using sharelatex doesn't work either:
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5323d40becd86cf06b0011c0?r=7cf90577&rs=ps&rm=d

Comment: @Nicolás, you might try adding `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` based on the second paragraph of section 3.13 of the `pgf` 2.10 manual. Failing that, I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I've just tested your answer with TexLive2013 (pgf 3.0.0) and works perfect. But I should want a solution working with the not so up-to-date pgf as well.

Answer (score 6):

The `append after command` key appends nothing after drawing the node. It appends material to the current path where the node entry appears. Here is an example to illustrate its usage.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)  -- (1,0) node{A} -- (2,0);
  \draw[red] (0,1)  -- (1,1)  node[append after command={-- +(0,1)}] {A}  -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: usage of append after command]

When TikZ draws a path with some nodes, first it draws the path (and collects all the nodes) then it draws the nodes. With TikZ 3.0, you may apply the `behind path` option to a node to draw it before the current path. Here is in example of its usage (combined with `append after command`):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  mainfig/.style={
    minimum width=16mm,minimum height=5mm,text centered,
    draw=black,fill=orange!80,
    line width=1pt,rectangle,
    append after command={
      ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(3mm,5mm)$)--
      ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(3mm,-5mm)$)
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
  \draw[line width=2pt,draw=blue] node [mainfig] {\ldots};
  \draw[line width=2pt,draw=red] (0,2) node [behind path,mainfig] {\ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of behind path]